# Python: how to get unique ID and remove duplicates from column 1 (ID), and column 3 (Description), Then get the median for column 2 (Value) in Pandas

Tags: python

Python: how to get unique ID and remove duplicates from column 1 (ID), and column 3 (Description), Then get the median for column 2

| ID | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 116 | xx |
| 123456 | 117 | xx |
| 123456 | 113 | xx |
| 123456 | 109 | xz |
| 123456 | 108 | xz |
| 123456 | 98 | xz |
| 121214 | 115 | abc |
| 121214 | 110 | abc |
| 121214 | 103 | abc |
| 121214 | 117 | abz |
| 121214 | 120 | abz |
| 121214 | 125 | abz |
| 151416 | 114 | zxc |
| 151416 | 135 | zxc |
| 151416 | 127 | zxc |
| 151416 | 145 | zxm |
| 151416 | 125 | zxm |
| 151416 | 121 | zxm |

Procced table should look like:

| ID | xx | xz | abc | abz | zxc | zxm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 110 | 151 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 121214 | 0 | 0 | 132 | 113 | 0 | 0 |
| 151416 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 124 | 115 |

Comment: It's recommended to add data as text rather than image, we can not copy the contents from image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the approach of the mean, but your "expected output" example doesn't give a mean. Is that me misunderstanding what you mean?

```
pd.pivot_table(DF, 'Value', index='ID', columns='Description')
```

Should do the trick, default math function is the mean, so that's ideal. More info can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) (mind you, DF is the to import dataframe).

Comment: Hi FoxSrk, I tried pivot_table pretty much the same code you have provided and I got an
error: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: That's on your dataframe then. I put your data in a CSV and `DF = pd.read_csv(path)`.
Check if that works, it seems like you're using incorrect types, but works perfectly here

Comment: `DF_NEW = pd.pivot_table(DF, 'Value', index='ID', columns='Description')
DF_NEW =DF_NEW.fillna(0).astype(int)`
Would actually be better, fyi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach will work for you?

```
d = {'ID': [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], 'Value': [5,6,7,8,9,7,8,5,1,2,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
unique = set(df['ID'])
value_mean = []
for i in unique:
  a = df[df['ID']==i]['Value']
  a = a.mean()
  value_mean.append(a)
```

Comment: Thanks John; how about the column description? how to include it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have e.g. 6 'ID' with value '123456'. If you only want unique 'ID', you need to remove 5 'ID' rows, by doing this you will not have duplicate 'Description' values anymore. The question is, do you want unique ID or unique Description values (or unique combination of both)?

Comment: Thanks John, well I'm looking for > (or unique combination of both) as seen in the 2nd table

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more options to solve this. What you could do is combine the ID and Description into a new column, and remove the duplicate in the DataFrame. Hopefully this would help.

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5],
     'Value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6],
     'Description': ['a','a','b','b','c','d','d','a','c','d','e','e','e','a','b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
unique_combined = []
for i in range(len(df)):
  unique_combined.append((str(df.iloc[i]['ID'])+ df.iloc[i]['Description']))
df['un'] = unique_combined
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['un'])
```